# List of related tags on 'Tag top users' page should not include the tag itself

Tags: bug

If not a bug, this at least is inconsistent behavior.

1. Go to any [tag info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug%20Tagged%20questions) or [tagged questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/info) page, say for 'bug'.
2. Check the list of related tags, note 'bug' itself is not present.
3. The [top users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/topusers) page, however, has 'bug' at the top of the list of related tags.

Similarly, any tag is listed at the top of the 'Related tags' list on the 'Top users' page, but not elsewhere.